# How can I do sync field validation based on a param with redux-form?

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I need sync field validation on a redux-form field. A param  for it (minimum value) is in the redux store.

How can I pass a param to a field validator function? Or even to the form's sync validator func.

As far as I understood I've two options to set field validation:

1. Pass a validate function to reduxForm()

If i go with this route how can I access the Form props from the validate function?
Even if I bind the validate function to the form it can't see the form's props.

```
App = reduxForm({
  form: "MyForm",
  validate: validate.bind(App)
})(App);
```

I could not either pass a MyForm.Validate function to the reduxForm.

2. Set a validate function using the validate prop on Field component

This route i would pass the prop as a parameter to the validation function.
Ie. `<Field validate={minValue(this.props.minValue)} />` 
[But in this comment](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2453#issuecomment-272483784) it is said is not a good way because it creates a new function on each form render. Indeed it  doesn't work properly - no validation until an other field's validation error occurs.

[My attempts on codepen](https://codepen.io/szert/pen/WZQQKZ?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround.

```
const Validations = {
  minAmount: minValue => value => {
    return parseFloat(value) < minValue
      ? "Amount must be at least " + minValue
      : undefined;
  }
};
```

in component constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.minAmount = Validations.minAmount(
        this.props.minAmount
    ); // this a a workaround for validations with parameters causing issues , see https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2453#issuecomment-272483784
}
```

then in Field:

```
<Field 
  validate={this.minAmount}
  ....
```